# How do I make this sprite clickable and then close it after so a new map can be rendered?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, mouseevent, sprite

I'm trying to make this sprite called `Button` clickable. It appears after the player has reached the goal, and after clicking it the sprite should dissapear for the new map. I'll also make it so after clicking the sprite the new level will be loaded in, but for now let's keep it at accomplishing the clicking the sprite and having something happen because of it.

This is the code of interest:

```
class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.buttons
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = pg.Surface((450, 335))
        self.image = game.alert_img        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._layer = 2
        self.rect.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = y * TILESIZE
```

---

```
def events(self):
    # catch all events here
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            self.quit()
        if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                self.quit()
            if event.key == pg.K_LEFT:
                self.player.move(dx=-1)
            if event.key == pg.K_RIGHT:
                self.player.move(dx=1)
            if event.key == pg.K_UP:
                self.player.move(dy=-1)
            if event.key == pg.K_DOWN:
                self.player.move(dy=1)
        if event.type == pg.USEREVENT + 1:
            self.text_object.kill()
            self.text_object = Text((1760, 570), self.player.actions, self.font)
            self.all_sprites.add(self.text_object)
            Button(self, self.player.x -1.5, self.player.y - 2.4)
```

Mind you, the events is in the main class, while class button, well, clearly isnt. My point being def events isn't in button class.

**EDIT**
Both anwsers down below work, however skrx his response is more fit towards my personal project, where my solution might be more suited for you depending on what you're trying to accomplish. I advise looking through both.

Comment: This question is a bit difficult to answer, especially for people who don't know your whole project. I think I'd give the `Game` class a `self.button = None` attribute and assign the button instance to this attribute when the goal is reached. The difficult part is to check for collisions with the mouse position, because of the camera offset. I'll try to figure out a solution and post it later.

Comment: Whoa, thanks! Also, first development on the microcontroller has started and it's making good progress!

Comment: Maybe instead of having the user click the sprite, I could start a form of wait for event, and the event being a key? So that way it still does what I want and I dont need to check any collision between the sprite and mouse pos. I'll look into that

Comment: I found something that might work, if I do it like this `pygame.event.clear()` to clear event cache. `event = pygame.event.wait()` to wait for an event in the event cache. And then something along these lines `elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key = K_f:
            do something...`

Comment: Yeah, you can just let the user press a key.

Comment: @skrx I found a way to do it which works, the whole clicking the sprite thing would've been far too hard for something this simple, thanks anyway though!

Comment: I'll post my solution as well, but there's still a little bug that I need to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give the `Game` class a `self.button = None` attribute and assign the button instance when the user reaches the goal. To check if the mouse collides with the button, you can use the `event.pos` of the `pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event and apply the camera. I had to give the `Camera` class a `apply_mouse` method, because the `event.pos` is just a tuple and I needed the negative camera position.

```
# In the `Game` class.
def events(self):
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            self.quit()
        elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if self.button is not None:
                mouse = self.camera.apply_mouse(event.pos)
                if self.button.rect.collidepoint(mouse):
                    print('Clicked!')
                    # Remove button from sprite groups and
                    # set self.button to None again.
                    button.kill()
                    self.button = None
        # KEYDOWN events omitted.
        elif event.type == pg.USEREVENT + 1:
            self.text_object.kill()
            self.text_object = Text((1760, 570), self.player.actions, self.font)
            self.all_sprites.add(self.text_object)
            # Check `if self.button is None` so that we don't add
            # several buttons to the groups.
            if self.button is None:
                self.button = Button(self, 1060, 670)


class Button(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.buttons
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.image = pg.Surface((450, 335))
        self.image.fill((0, 40, 200))  
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self._layer = 6


class Camera:
    # I just added this method to the Camera class.
    def apply_mouse(self, pos):
        return (pos[0]-self.camera.x, pos[1]-self.camera.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

So instead of having the user click the sprite, I instead made a function called `continue_game` in which the game comes to a halt and waits for the user to press the space bar for the game to continue, I have no substantial code being run after space is run, but the kill does remove the sprite how I want it to, ensuring me this does what I want it to.

```
def continue_game(self):
    user_continue = False
    while not user_continue:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.quit()
                if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                    self.button.kill()
                    user_continue = True
```

The previously mentioned userevent now looks like this:

```
if event.type == pg.USEREVENT + 1:
            self.text_object.kill()
            self.text_object = Text((1760, 570), self.player.actions, self.font)
            self.all_sprites.add(self.text_object)
            self.button = Button(self, self.player.x -1.5, self.player.y - 2.4)
            self.draw()
            self.continue_game()
```

Comment: You also need to call `self.clock.tick(FPS)` in this while loop.

Comment: Made an edit stating that your solution is fit towards my project where mine is more generally fit, still wanting to say, yours is definetly better.